# Visual Studio 2013 update 5 Web site

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vs-web-application-project

i have serious problěm with VS 2013, I updated to update 5 and now i can't build my website project. 
I have some files in App_code folder, in VS u 4 it worked, in u5 there is no build action in properties. I tried to delete app_code folder and recreate, have deleted all tempomary data etc, but hnothing worked?

Do you have any idea what to do? i don't want to reinstall whole VS.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is uninstall VS 2013 Update 5 and see if it helps.

Open up the control panel in Windows.  Click Programs and click view installed updates and search for "Visual Studio 2015 Update 5."  Right click on it and select uninstall.